# Audio and Animation is not synced on iPad app created using Flash cs6

Tags: ios, flash, animation, audio, synchronization

I have animation along with sound in separate layer. The animation is fairly long around 1415 frames, and the audio is also having equal length. The animation/audio sync is very good when I run in on PC but the problem occurs after create an app for iOS and run it from iPad. The animation lags behind the audio on iPad.

I am using Flash CS6 and iPad 1 for testing.

Your inputs are valuable, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the iOs device dynamically controls the frame rate of the application. Though animations contains rich graphics the frame rate automatically reduces. The animation playing very slowly and the animation and audio mismatches.

Why don't you avail the sprite sheet feature of FLASH CS6 to play your animation very smooth in the device. This mainly enhanced this feature for this purpose only.

Here is the link to start using sprite sheet http://blogs.adobe.com/flashpro/2012/07/12/spritesheet-flashpro-starling/

Comment: Thanks Moorthy, I will give it a try.

Comment: A good suggestion, if you don't go that route, at the very least break up your audio as much as possible so it's a new clip every xx amount of frames, that way it re-syncs on the next audio clip.  You just have to be careful because then you can get overlapping audio if its dropping a lot of frames.  It's more work, but it's better to sync your animation to completion events in audio rather than audio to timeline events.